# Generating list of alphabet letters

Tags: function-construction, symbols

I want to create a list of length `n` with the letters of the alphabet.

For example, if `n = 3`, by list would be `{a,b,c}`.  If `n=6`, the list would be `{a,b,c,d,e,f}`.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 16):

No need to use `*CharacterCode[]` :

```
letters[n_] := CharacterRange["a", "z"][[;; n]]

letters[3]
(*
{"a", "b", "c"}
*)
```

Comment: I'd say ugly but nice :)

Comment: Ha, it works even with non-Latin alphabets.. It is new for me, that Mathematica can correctly understand Cyrillic ranges of symbols :)

Comment: @Rom38 It works with all letters of all types that exist as a contiguous block in the character space.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but just 3-4 years ago Mathematica had permanent problems with Cyrillic alphabet (mostly regarded to encodings)

Answer (score 13):

Nowadays, one can use `Alphabet[]` along with `Take[]` or `Part[]` + `Span[]`:

```
Take[Alphabet[], 6]
   {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}

Take[Alphabet[], {19, UpTo[28]}]
   {"s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
```

In addition to this, `Alphabet[]` is aware of alphabets other than the Latin alphabet:

```
Take[Alphabet["Greek"], 5]
   {"α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε"}

Take[Alphabet["Hebrew"], {4, 8}]
   {"ד", "ה", "ו", "ז", "ח"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 lttrsF = FromCharacterCode /@ (ToCharacterCode[#][[1]] + Range[0, #2-1]) &
 lttrsF["b", 4]
 (*  {"b", "c", "d", "e"}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [`FromCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FromCharacterCode.html):

> `FromCharacterCode[n]`:
>
> gives a string consisting of the character with integer code n.

```
letters[n_] := StringSplit[FromCharacterCode[Range[97, 97 + n - 1]], ""]
letters@3
```

> {"a", "b", "c"}